# Any simple way to explain why I cannot do List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Dog>()?

Tags: java, generics, oop, covariance

I know why one shouldn't do that. But is there way to explain to a layman why this is not possible. You can explain this to a layman easily : `Animal animal = new Dog();`. A dog is a kind of animal but a list of dogs is not a list of animals.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/tags/Covariance%20and%20Contravariance/default.aspx

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Imagine you create a list of **Dogs**. You then declare this as **List<Animal>** and hand it to a colleague. He, *not unreasonably*, believes he can put a **Cat** in it.

He then gives it back to you, and you now have a list of **Dogs**, with a **Cat** in the middle of it. Chaos ensues.

It's important to note that this restriction is there due to the mutability of the list. In Scala (for example), you can declare that a list of **Dogs** is a list of **Animals**. That's because Scala lists are (by default) immutable, and so adding a **Cat** to a list of **Dogs** would give you a *new* list of **Animals**.

Comment: I like this one because of "dogs and cats living together" references.  Though I think "ensures" is probably meant to be "ensues".  Note: once this answer is fully understood this is the perfect gateway into what List<? extends Animal> is for and it's limitations on which methods you can call become more obvious (ie: can't call add() but can call get(), etc.)

Comment: 'Ensues', indeed. Now edited.

Comment: Also this answer seems to be the only one that described it anywhere close to "way to explain to a layman".  While I'm pointing out potential typos, the bolded "List" in the second sentence may need some kind of "Animals" attribution.

Comment: Thx. Got lost in the formatting!

Comment: Good answer, accepted for the 'chaos ensues'.

Answer (score 8):

The answer you're looking for is to do with concepts called covariance and contravariance.  Some languages support these (.NET 4 adds support, for example), but some of the basic problems are demonstrated by code like this:

```
List<Animal> animals = new List<Dog>();

animals.Add(myDog); // works fine - this is a list of Dogs
animals.Add(myCat); // would compile fine if this were allowed, but would crash!
```

Because Cat would derive from animal, a compile-time check would suggest that it can be added to List.  But, at runtime, you can't add a Cat to a list of Dogs!

So, though it may seem intuitively simple, these problems are actually very complex do deal with.

There's an MSDN overview of co/contravariance in .NET 4 here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(VS.100).aspx - it's all applicable to java too, though I don't know what Java's support is like.

Answer (score 8):

The best layman answer I can give is this: **because in designing generics they do not want to repeat the same decision that was made to Java's array type system that made it unsafe**.

This is possible with arrays:

```
Object[] objArray = new String[] { "Hello!" };
objArray[0] = new Object();
```

**This code compiles just fine** because of the way array's type system works in Java. It would raise an `ArrayStoreException` at run time.

The decision was made not to allow such unsafe behavior for generics.

See also elsewhere: [Java Arrays Break Type Safety](http://c2.com/cgi-bin/wiki?JavaArraysBreakTypeSafety), which many considers one of [Java Design Flaws](http://c2.com/cgi-bin/wiki?JavaDesignFlaws).

Answer (score 5):

A **List<Animal>** is an object where you can insert any animal, for example a cat or an octopus. An **ArrayList<Dog>** isn't.

Answer (score 5):

What you're trying to do is the following:

```
List<? extends Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Dog>()
```

That should work.

Comment: Does this explain it to a layman ? I don't think so.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say the simplest answer is to ignore the cats and dogs, they aren't relevant.  What's important is the list itself.

```
List<Dog>
```

and

```
List<Animal>
```

are different types, that Dog derives from Animal has no bearing on this at all.

This statement is invalid

```
List<Animal> dogs = new List<Dog>();
```

for the same reason this one is

```
AnimalList dogs = new DogList();
```

While Dog may inherit from Animal, the list class generated by

```
List<Animal>
```

doesn't inherit from the list class generated by

```
List<Dog>
```

It's a mistake to assume that because two classes are related that using them as generic parameters will then make those generic classes also be related.  While you could certainly add a dog to a

```
List<Animal>
```

that doesn't imply that

```
List<Dog>
```

is a subclass of

```
List<Animal>
```

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you *could* do this. One of the things that someone handed a `List<Animal>` would reasonably expect to be able to do is to add a `Giraffe` to it. What should happen when someone tries to add a `Giraffe` to `animals`? A run time error? That would seem to defeat the purpose of compile-time typing.

Comment: If I add a `Giraffe` to it why would it give a run time error? If I do `animals.get()` I can only expect an `animal` and a `Giraffe` is an `animal`. It will be weird to put in a  `Giraffe` in `ArrayList<Dog>()` but I don't see any run time error. All types are erased at runtime.

Comment: The runtime error will come from other code that might still be using your ArrayList<Dog> and properly expects that it only contains Dogs.  Also, from the theoretical perspective, erasure is an implementation detail in this context.

Comment: @PSpeed - Yeah that will true if you have a separate reference to `ArrayList<Dog>` as in Rune's answer. If not, everything would be fine, right?

Comment: Then why declare ArrayList<Dog> instead of ArrayList<Animal>.  You are subverting the typing system otherwise... and then what's the point? :)

Comment: ...and besides, like I said, the fact that Java is erasing the type of ArrayList is an implementation detail.  If some other class Foo actually doesn't erase its type because maybe it takes it on the constructor, then it _can_ check types and give you runtime errors.  The fact that Java doesn't provide truly type safe collections is mostly a matter of backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that if you have

```
List<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<Dog>()
```

then, if you could do

```
List<Animal> animals = dogs;
```

this does *not* turn `dogs` into a `List<Animal>`. The data structure underlying animals is still an `ArrayList<Dog>`, so if you try to insert an `Elephant` into `animals`, you are actually inserting it into an `ArrayList<Dog>` which is not going to work (the Elephant is obviously way too big ;-).

Comment: Yeah that will true if you have a separate reference to `ArrayList<Dog>`. If not, everything would be fine, right?

Answer (score 2):

First, let's define our animal kingdom:

```
interface Animal {
}

class Dog implements Animal{
    Integer dogTag() {
        return 0;
    }
}

class Doberman extends Dog {        
}
```

Consider two parameterized interfaces:

```
interface Container<T> {
    T get();
}

interface Comparator<T> {
    int compare(T a, T b);
}
```

And implementations of these where `T` is `Dog`.

```
class DogContainer implements Container<Dog> {
    private Dog dog;

    public Dog get() {
        dog = new Dog();
        return dog;
    }
}

class DogComparator implements Comparator<Dog> {
    public int compare(Dog a, Dog b) {
        return a.dogTag().compareTo(b.dogTag());
    }
}
```

What you are asking is quite reasonable in the context of this `Container` interface:

```
Container<Dog> kennel = new DogContainer();

// Invalid Java because of invariance.
// Container<Animal> zoo = new DogContainer();

// But we can annotate the type argument in the type of zoo to make
// to make it co-variant.
Container<? extends Animal> zoo = new DogContainer();
```

So why doesn't Java do this automatically? Consider what this would mean for `Comparator`.

```
Comparator<Dog> dogComp = new DogComparator();

// Invalid Java, and nonsensical -- we couldn't use our DogComparator to compare cats!
// Comparator<Animal> animalComp = new DogComparator();

// Invalid Java, because Comparator is invariant in T
// Comparator<Doberman> dobermanComp = new DogComparator();

// So we introduce a contra-variance annotation on the type of dobermanComp.
Comparator<? super Doberman> dobermanComp = new DogComparator();
```

If Java automatically allowed `Container<Dog>` to be assigned to `Container<Animal>`, one would also expect that a `Comparator<Dog>` could be assigned to a `Comparator<Animal>`, which makes no sense -- how could a `Comparator<Dog>` compare two Cats?

So what is the difference between `Container` and `Comparator`? Container **produces** values of the type `T`, whereas `Comparator` **consumes** them. These correspond to **covariant** and **contra-variant** usages of of the type parameter.

Sometimes the type parameter is used in both positions, making the interface **invariant**.

```
interface Adder<T> {
   T plus(T a, T b);
}

Adder<Integer> addInt = new Adder<Integer>() {
   public Integer plus(Integer a, Integer b) {
        return a + b;
   }
};
Adder<? extends Object> aObj = addInt;
// Obscure compile error, because it there Adder is not usable
// unless T is invariant.
//aObj.plus(new Object(), new Object());
```

For backwards compatibility reasons, Java defaults to **invariance**. You must explicitly choose the appropriate variance with `? extends X` or `? super X` on the types of the variables, fields, parameters, or method returns.

This is a real hassle -- every time someone uses the a generic type, they must make this decision! Surely the authors of `Container` and `Comparator` should be able to declare this once and for all.

This is called 'Declaration Site Variance', and is available in Scala.

```
trait Container[+T] { ... }
trait Comparator[-T] { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you couldn't mutate the list then your reasoning would be perfectly sound. Unfortunately a  `List<>` is manipulated imperatively. Which means you can change a `List<Animal>` by adding a new `Animal` to it. If you were allowed to use a `List<Dog>` as a `List<Animal>` you could wind up with a list that also contains a `Cat`.

If `List<>` was incapable of mutation (like in Scala), then you could treat A `List<Dog>` as a `List<Animal>`. For instance, C# makes this behavior possible with covariant and contravariant generics type arguments.

This is an instance of the more general [Liskov substitution principal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

The fact that mutation causes you an issue here happens elsewhere. Consider the types `Square` and `Rectangle`.

Is a `Square` a `Rectangle`? Certainly -- from a mathematical perspective.

You could define a `Rectangle` class which offers readable `getWidth` and `getHeight` properties.

You could even add methods that calculate its `area` or `perimeter`, based on those properties.

You could then define a `Square` class that subclasses `Rectangle` and makes both `getWidth` and `getHeight` return the same value.

But what happens when you start allowing mutation via `setWidth` or `setHeight`?

Now, `Square` is no longer a reasonable subclass of `Rectangle`. Mutating one of those properties would have to silently change the other in order to maintain the invariant, and Liskov's substitution principal would be violated. Changing the width of a `Square` would have an unexpected side-effect. In order to remain a square you would have to change the height as well, but you only asked to change the width!

You can't use your `Square` whenever you could have used a `Rectangle`. So, *in the presence of mutation* a `Square` is not a `Rectangle`!

You could make a new method on `Rectangle` that knows how to clone the rectangle with a new width or a new height, and then your `Square` could safely devolve to a `Rectangle` during the cloning process, but now you are no longer mutating the original value.

Similarly a `List<Dog>` cannot be a `List<Animal>` when its interface empowers you to add new items to the list.

Answer (score 1):

This is because generic types are [invariant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_%28computer_science%29).

Answer (score 0):

**English Answer:**

If '`List<Dog>` is a `List<Animal>`', the former must support (inherit) all operations of the latter.  Adding a cat can be done to latter, but not former.  So the 'is a' relationship fails.

**Programming Answer:**

### Type Safety

A conservative language default design choice that stops this corruption:

```
List<Dog> dogs = new List<>();
dogs.add(new Dog("mutley"));
List<Animal> animals = dogs;
animals.add(new Cat("felix"));  
// Yikes!! animals and dogs refer to same object.  dogs now contains a cat!!
```

---

In order to have a subtype relationship, must sastify 'castability'/'substitability' criteria.

1. **Legal object substition - all operations on ancestor supported on decendant:**

   ```
   // Legal - one object, two references (cast to different type)
   Dog dog = new Dog();
   Animal animal = dog;
   ```
2. **Legal collection substitution - all operations on ancestor supported on descendant:**

   ```
   // Legal - one object, two references (cast to different type)
   List<Animal> list = new List<Animal>()
   Collection<Animal> coll = list;
   ```
3. **Illegal generic substitution (cast of type parameter) - unsupported ops in decendant:**

   ```
   // Illegal - one object, two references (cast to different type), but not typesafe
   List<Dog> dogs = new List<Dog>()
   List<Animal> animals = list;  // would-be ancestor has broader ops than decendant
   ```

---

### However

Depending on the design of the generic class, type parameters can used in 'safe positions', meaning that casting/substitution can sometimes succeed without corrupting type safety.  Covariance means generic instatition `G<U>` can substitute `G<T>` if U is a same type or subtype of T.  Contravariance means generic instantion `G<U>` can substitue `G<T>` if U is a same type or supertype of T.  These are the safe positions for the 2 cases:

- **covariant positions:**

  - **method return type** (output of generic type) - subtypes must be equally/more restrictive, so their return types comply with ancestor
  - **type of immutable fields** (set by owner class, then 'internally output-only') - subtypes must be more restrictive, so when they set immutable fields, they comply with ancestor

  In these cases it's safe to allow substitutability of a type parameter with a decendant like this:

  ```
  SomeCovariantType<Dog> decendant = new SomeCovariantType<>;
  SomeCovariantType<? extends Animal> ancestor = decendant;
  ```

  The wildcard plus 'extends' gives usage-site specified covariance.
- **contrvariant positions:**

  - **method parameter type** (input to generic type) - subtypes must be equally/more accommodating so they don't break when passed parameters of ancestor
  - **upper type parameter bounds** (internal type instantiation) - subtypes must be equally/more accommodating, so they don't break when ancestors set variable values

  In these cases it's safe to allow substitutability of a type parameter with an ancestor like this:

  ```
  SomeContravariantType<Animal> decendant = new SomeContravariantType<>;
  SomeContravariantType<? super Dog> ancestor = decendant;
  ```

  The wildcard plus 'super' gives usage-site specified contravariance.

Using these 2 idioms takes extra effort and care from the developer to gain 'substitutability power'. Java requires manual developer effort to ensure the type parameters are truly used in covariant/contravariant positions, respectively (hence type-safe).  I know not why - e.g. scala compiler checks this :-/.  You're basically telling the compiler 'trust me, I know what I'm doing, this is type-safe'.

- **invariant positions**

  - **type of mutable field** (internal input and output) - can be read and written by all ancestor and subtype classes - reading is covariant, writing is contravariant; result is invariant
  - (also if type parameter is used in both covariant and contravariant positions, then this results in invariance)

Answer (score -1):

By inheriting you are actually creating common type for several classes  . Here you have a common animal type . you are using it by creating an array in type of Animal and keeping values of similar types(inherited types dog, cat ,etc..).

Eg:

```
 dim animalobj as new List(Animal)
  animalobj(0)=new dog()
   animalobj(1)=new Cat()
```

.......

Got it?