# Bounding generics with 'super' keyword

Tags: java, generics, language-design, super

Why can I use `super` only with wildcards and not with type parameters?

For example, in the `Collection` interface, why is the `toArray` method not written like this

```
interface Collection<T>{
    <S super T> S[] toArray(S[] a);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you semantically intend to be the difference between <S super T> and <? super T>. Seems to me it's just splitting hairs over syntax.

Comment: You can't do `? super T[] toArray(? super T[] a)`, can you?

Comment: And this is why there is an `Object[] toArray()` method in the Collection class.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`super` to bound a named type parameter (e.g. `<S super T>`) as opposed to a wildcard (e.g. `<? super T>`) is **ILLEGAL** simply because even if it's allowed, it wouldn't do what you'd hoped it would do, because since `Object` is the ultimate `super` of all reference types, and everything is an `Object`, *in effect there is no bound*.

In your specific example, since *any* array of reference type is an `Object[]` (by Java array covariance), it can therefore be used as an argument to `<S super T> S[] toArray(S[] a)` (if such bound is legal) at compile-time, and it wouldn't prevent `ArrayStoreException` at run-time.

What you're trying to propose is that given:

```
List<Integer> integerList;
```

and given this *hypothetical* `super` bound on `toArray`:

```
<S super T> S[] toArray(S[] a) // hypothetical! currently illegal in Java
```

the compiler should only allow the following to compile:

```
integerList.toArray(new Integer[0]) // works fine!
integerList.toArray(new Number[0])  // works fine!
integerList.toArray(new Object[0])  // works fine!
```

and no other array type arguments (since `Integer` only has those 3 types as `super`). That is, you're trying to prevent this from compiling:

```
integerList.toArray(new String[0])  // trying to prevent this from compiling
```

because, by your argument, `String` is not a `super` of `Integer`. *However*, `Object` is a `super` of `Integer`, and a `String[]` is an `Object[]`, so the compiler *still* would let the above compile, even if hypothetically you can do `<S super T>`!

So the following *would still compile* (just as the way they are right now), and `ArrayStoreException` at run-time could not be prevented by any compile-time checking using generic type bounds:

```
integerList.toArray(new String[0])  // compiles fine!
// throws ArrayStoreException at run-time
```

Generics and arrays don't mix, and this is one of the many places where it shows.

---

#### A non-array example

Again, let's say that you have this generic method declaration:

```
<T super Integer> void add(T number) // hypothetical! currently illegal in Java
```

And you have these variable declarations:

```
Integer anInteger
Number aNumber
Object anObject
String aString
```

Your intention with `<T super Integer>` (if it's legal) is that it should allow `add(anInteger)`, and `add(aNumber)`, and of course `add(anObject)`, but NOT `add(aString)`. Well, `String` is an `Object`, so `add(aString)` would still compile anyway.

---

#### See also

- [Java Tutorials/Generics](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html)

  - [Subtyping](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/generics/subtype.html)
  - [More fun with wildcards](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/generics/morefun.html)

#### Related questions

On generics typing rules:

- [Any simple way to explain why I cannot do `List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Dog>()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346763/any-simple-way-to-explain-why-i-cannot-do-listanimal-animals-new-arraylistdo)
- [java generics (not) covariance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660827/java-generics-covariance)
- [What is a raw type and why shouldn’t we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it/)

  - Explains how raw type `List` is different from `List<Object>` which is different from a `List<?>`

On using `super` and `extends`:

- [`Java Generics: What is PECS?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs)

  - From *Effective Java 2nd Edition*: "producer `extends` consumer `super`"
- [What is the difference between `super` and `extends` in Java Generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910892/what-is-the-difference-between-super-and-extends-in-java-generics)
- [What is the difference between `<E extends Number>` and `<Number>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770264/what-is-the-difference-between-e-extends-number-and-number/)
- [How can I add to `List<? extends Number>` data structures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776975/how-can-i-add-to-list-extends-number-data-structures) (YOU CAN'T!)

Comment: This way Collection"<? super Integer> should take every thing. Because every thing is Object and Object is super type of Integer.

Comment: @mohsenof: even though `String` is an `Object`, a `Collection<String>` is not a `Collection<? super Integer>`, because generics are invariant: a `Collection<String>` is NOT a `Collection<Object>`. A `String[]` however is an `Object[]`, because arrays are covariant. Again, generics and arrays don't mix, and they run under very different type rules. Read _Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 25: Prefer lists to arrays_.

Comment: so why would

    <S super T> List<S> addToList(List<S> list, T element){
        list.add(element);
        return list;
    }

not make sense?

Comment: "it wouldn't do what you'd hoped" - this is just plain wrong. The OP provided a great use case (modulo the dreaded array covariance) with obvious semantics: the collection should be able to fill the array of any more general type and return the said array. There is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: "since any array of reference type is an `Object[]`, it can therefore be used as an argument to `<S super T> S[] toArray(S[] a)`" True. However, if `S` were inferred to be `Object`, then that would also constrain the return type of the method to `Object[]`, which may cause a compile error depending on the context in which the call is made (if it expects a `S[]`). So changing the type variable to `Object` is not a substitute for a `super` bound.

Comment: there are some, though few, valid use cases for lower bounds.

Comment: polygenelubricants: The main point in this answer, that upper type bound are not useful, is incorrect. This is demonstrated in Rotsor's answer. I would like to encourage you to edit this answer to point this out, because in its current form it is misleading people!

Comment: @polygenelubricants,  `<? super T>` is **ILLEGAL**!! Are you sure!!

Comment: -1 This is answer is incorrect. The real answer is because "They designed Java that way". See Rotsor's answer for valid (and extremely useful) use cases that are invalid code only because of the Java specifications, not because the logic is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, the answer is wrong. It sounds convincing at first but it's nonsense. `T super String` means `T` is either `Object`, `CharSequence` or `String` - but not anything else. Clearly that is a real - and useful - bound.

Comment: What if the hypothetical clause `<S super T>` is allowed, and if we were to use it along with a classy alternative such as `Class<S>`. Then we would be able to solve this problem? So the new version of `toArray` would be: `<S super T> S[] toArray(Class<S> a)`

Answer (score 51):

As no one has provided a satisfactory answer, the correct answer seems to be "for no good reason".

polygenelubricants provided a good overview of bad things happening with the java array covariance, which is a terrible feature by itself. Consider the following code fragment:

```
String[] strings = new String[1];
Object[] objects = strings;
objects[0] = 0;
```

This obviously wrong code compiles without resorting to any "super" construct, so array covariance should not be used as an argument.

Now, here I have a perfectly valid example of code requiring `super` in the named type parameter:

```
class Nullable<A> {
    private A value;
    // Does not compile!!
    public <B super A> B withDefault(B defaultValue) {
        return value == null ? defaultValue : value;
    }
}
```

Potentially supporting some nice usage:

```
Nullable<Integer> intOrNull = ...;
Integer i = intOrNull.withDefault(8);
Number n = intOrNull.withDefault(3.5);
Object o = intOrNull.withDefault("What's so bad about a String here?");
```

The latter code fragment does not compile if I remove the `B` altogether, so `B` is indeed needed.

Note that the feature I'm trying to implement is easily obtained if I invert the order of type parameter declarations, thus changing the `super` constraint to `extends`. However, this is only possible if I rewrite the method as a static one:

```
// This one actually works and I use it.
public static <B, A extends B> B withDefault(Nullable<A> nullable, B defaultValue) { ... }
```

The point is that this Java language restriction is indeed restricting some otherwise possible useful features and may require ugly workarounds. I wonder what would happen if we needed `withDefault` to be virtual.

Now, to correlate with what polygenelubricants said, we use `B` here not to restrict the type of object passed as `defaultValue` (see the String used in the example), but rather to restrict the caller expectations about the object we return. As a simple rule, you use `extends` with the types you demand and `super` with the types you provide.

Comment: +1 Your example matches up with a real-world use case in Guava's [`Optional.or(T)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html#or\(T\)). From the documentation: "The signature `public T or(T defaultValue)` is overly restrictive. However, the ideal signature, `public <S super T> S or(S)`, is not legal Java. As a result, some sensible operations involving subtypes are compile errors".

Comment: @PaulBellora …and now that Java has its own `Optional` or the Stream API, it’s biting everyone. The best you can do then, is an actually obsolete `.<SuperType>map(t -> t)` or `.map(Function.<SuperType>identity())`…

Comment: @Holger I actually remember this definition and explanation in the guava's doc. I *still* can't understand why one would want to return a super type; for me it just defeats the purpose, it makes perfect sense to return a subtype, I guess I am missing something here

Comment: @Eugene this answer’s examples should be explanatory enough; just replace `Nullable` with `Optional` and `withDefault` with `orElse`. Another example would be `CompletableFuture<CharBuffer> f = someIoOperation();   CharSequence result = f.exceptionally(t -> "constant fallback").join();`, which would be a reasonable operation, but doesn’t work, unless you insert a workaround like `.thenApply(Function.<CharSequence>identity())`. Another indirect example would be `String.join(", ", () -> Stream.of("foo", "bar").iterator());`, which doesn’t work.

Comment: @Rotsor, can you please explain why the valid variant of method that you proposed in the end of post can be written only as `static`? 
I mean this declaration: `public static <B, A extends B> B withDefault(Nullable<A> nullable, B defaultValue) { ... }`.

Comment: You can't make that be a non-static method of a `Nullable<A>` class (and use `this` instead of `nullable`) because then you can't express the necessary constraint between `B` and `A` (as shown).
You could still add it as a non-static method to another class, but that would be useless because we don't use any instances of that class.

Comment: @Rotsor, ah, so the only reason of that method being `static` is the declaration of class `Nullable<A>` in a form, in which we don't have `B` in type parameters, got it, thank you. If we could rewrite this class like `Nullable<B, A extends B>`, then this method could be non-static.

Comment: Ah, yes, something like that could work, but: 1) the choice of `B` would have to be made when constructing the instance of such class; 2) I don't know if constraints are allowed at all in type parameters of a class and what exactly their meaning would be.

Comment: Another example of where this would be useful is [`Stream.concat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#concat(java.util.stream.Stream,java.util.stream.Stream)). I always wondered why this was not designed as an instance method so you could write `stream.map(...).filter(...).concat(...)`. Now I understand...

Answer (score 26):

The "official" answer to your question can be found in a [Sun/Oracle bug report](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8061427).

> BT2:EVALUATION
>
> See
>
> http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~odersky/ftp/local-ti.ps
>
> particularly section 3 and the last paragraph on page 9. Admitting
>   type variables on both sides of subtype constraints can result in a
>   set of type equations with no single best solution; consequently,
>   type inference cannot be done using any of the existing standard
>   algorithms. That is why type variables have only "extends" bounds.
>
> Wildcards, on the other hand, do not have to be inferred, so there
>   is no need for this constraint.
>
> #### @###.### 2004-05-25
>
> Yes; the key point is that wildcards, even when captured, are only used
>   as inputs of the inference process; nothing with (only) a lower bound needs
>   to be inferred as a result.
>
> #### @###.### 2004-05-26
>
> I see the problem. But I do not see how it is different from the problems
>   we have with lower bounds on wildcards during inference, e.g.:
>
> List<? super Number> s;
>   boolean b;
>   ...
>   s = b ? s : s;
>
> Currently, we infer List<X> where X extends Object as the type of the
>   conditional expression, meaning that the assignment is illegal.
>
> #### @###.### 2004-05-26

Sadly, the conversation ends there. The paper to which the (now dead) link used to point is [Inferred Type Instantiation for GJ](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~odersky/papers/localti02.html). From glancing at the last page, it boils down to: If lower bounds are admitted, type inference may yield multiple solutions, none of which is [principal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_type).

Comment: Underappreciated answer, should be accepted. Lower bounds in method type parameters are useful (as Rotsor showed) and can be implemented (as the author of that paper showed when he did so in Scala). Them being _hard_ to implement sensibly is clearly the real reason they aren't allowed in Java.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason is it makes no sense when declaring a type parameter with a super keyword when defining at a class level.
The only logical type-erasure strategy for Java would have been to fallback to the supertype of all objects, which is the Object class.

A great example and explanation can be found here:
http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#Why%20is%20there%20no%20lower%20bound%20for%20type%20parameters?

A simple example for rules of type-erasure can be found here:
[https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_generics/java_generics_type_erasure.htm#:~:text=Type%20erasure%20is%20a%20process,there%20is%20no%20runtime%20overhead](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_generics/java_generics_type_erasure.htm#:%7E:text=Type%20erasure%20is%20a%20process,there%20is%20no%20runtime%20overhead).

Answer (score -1):

Suppose we have:

- basic classes  A > B > C   and D

  ```
  class A{
      void methodA(){}
  };
  class B extends  A{
      void methodB(){}
  }

  class C extends  B{
      void methodC(){}
  }

  class D {
      void methodD(){}
  }
  ```
- job wrapper classes

  ```
  interface Job<T> {
      void exec(T t);
  }

  class JobOnA implements Job<A>{
      @Override
      public void exec(A a) {
          a.methodA();
      }
  }
  class JobOnB implements Job<B>{
      @Override
      public void exec(B b) {
          b.methodB();
      }
  }

  class JobOnC implements Job<C>{
      @Override
      public void exec(C c) {
          c.methodC();
      }
  }

  class JobOnD implements Job<D>{
      @Override
      public void exec(D d) {
          d.methodD();
      }
  }
  ```
- and one manager class with 4 different approaches to execute job on object

  ```
  class Manager<T>{
      final T t;
      Manager(T t){
          this.t=t;
      }
      public void execute1(Job<T> job){
          job.exec(t);
      }

      public <U> void execute2(Job<U> job){
          U u= (U) t;  //not safe
          job.exec(u);
      }

      public <U extends T> void execute3(Job<U> job){
          U u= (U) t; //not safe
          job.exec(u);
      }

      //desired feature, not compiled for now
      public <U super T> void execute4(Job<U> job){
          U u= (U) t; //safe
          job.exec(u);
      }
  }
  ```
- with usage

  ```
  void usage(){
      B b = new B();
      Manager<B> managerB = new Manager<>(b);

      //TOO STRICT
      managerB.execute1(new JobOnA());
      managerB.execute1(new JobOnB()); //compiled
      managerB.execute1(new JobOnC());
      managerB.execute1(new JobOnD());

      //TOO MUCH FREEDOM
      managerB.execute2(new JobOnA()); //compiled
      managerB.execute2(new JobOnB()); //compiled
      managerB.execute2(new JobOnC()); //compiled !!
      managerB.execute2(new JobOnD()); //compiled !!

      //NOT ADEQUATE RESTRICTIONS     
      managerB.execute3(new JobOnA());
      managerB.execute3(new JobOnB()); //compiled
      managerB.execute3(new JobOnC()); //compiled !!
      managerB.execute3(new JobOnD());

      //SHOULD BE
      managerB.execute4(new JobOnA());  //compiled
      managerB.execute4(new JobOnB());  //compiled
      managerB.execute4(new JobOnC());
      managerB.execute4(new JobOnD());
  }
  ```

Any suggestions how to implement execute4 now ?

==========edited =======

```
    public void execute4(Job<? super  T> job){
        job.exec( t);
    }
```

Thanks to all :)

========== edited ==========

```
    private <U> void execute2(Job<U> job){
        U u= (U) t;  //now it's safe
        job.exec(u);
    }
    public void execute4(Job<? super  T> job){
        execute2(job);
    }
```

much better, any code with U inside execute2

super type  U becomes named  !

interesting discussion :)

Answer (score -1):

I really like the accepted answer, but I would like to put a slightly different perspective on it.

`super` is supported in a typed parameter only to allow **contravariance** capabilities. When it comes to **covariance** and **contravariance** it's important to understand that Java only supports **use-site variance**. Unlike Kotlin or Scala, which allow **declaration-site variance**. Kotlin documentation explains it very well [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html). Or if you're more into Scala, [here](https://medium.com/javarevisited/variance-in-java-and-scala-63af925d21dc)'s one for you.

It basically means that in Java, you can not limit the way you're gonna use your class when you declare it in terms of PECS. The class can both consume and produce, and some of its methods can do it at the same time, like `toArray([])`, by the way.

Now, the reason `extends` is allowed in classes and methods declarations is because it's more about **polymorphism** than it is about **variance**. And **polymorphism** is an intrinsic part of Java and OOP in general: *If a method can accept some supertype, a subtype can always safely be passed to it. And if a method, at declaration site as it's "contract", should return some supertype, it's totally fine if it returns a subtype instead in its implementations*

Comment: The accepted answer is wrong. It's correct that this question is about type bounds and not about variance. But lower type bounds using `T super R` would sometimes be useful, as Rotsors' answer demonstrates, and also the reference to the Guava [`Optional`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/b72102d427be43b5c092042c9a9e5d972d55510c/guava/src/com/google/common/base/Optional.java#L187) class.