# Use generic to store common supertype in Java

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

Suppose I have a method "mix" that takes two Lists of possibly different types T and S and returns a single List containing the elements of both. For type-safety, I'd like to specify that the returned List is of a type R, where R is a supertype common to both T and S. For example:

```
List<Number> foo = mix(
    Arrays.asList<Integer>(1, 2, 3),
    Arrays.asList<Double>(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)
);
```

To specify this, I could declare the method as

```
static <R, T extends R, S extends R> List<R> mix(List<T> ts, List<S> ss)
```

But what if I want to make `mix` an instance method instead of static, on the class `List2<T>`?

```
<R, T extends R, S extends R> List<R> mix ...
```

shadows the `<T>` on the instance of `List2`, so that's no good.

```
<R, T extends S&T, S extends R> List<R> mix ...
```

solves the shadowing problem, but isn't accepted by the compiler

```
<R super T, S extends R> List<R> mix ...
```

is rejected by the compiler because lower-bounded wildcards can't be stored in a named variable (only used in `? super X` expressions)

I could move the arguments to the class itself, like `List2<R, T extends R, S extends R>`, but the type information really has no business being on the instance level, because it's only used for one method call, and you would have to re-cast the object every time you wanted to invoke the method on different arguments.

As far as I can tell, there's no way to do this with generics. The best I can do would be to return a raw `List2` and cast it at the callsite, like before generics were introduced. Does anybody have a better solution?

Comment: Why do you have `S extends T` instead of `S extends R`?

Comment: Also, it would be better if you can show the body of your method - `mix`. What exactly are you doing in it? Do you really need those those type parameters? It looks like you can go with bounded wildcards instead.

Comment: In fact, I don't understand the need of `R` type parameter. Since you just intend to return a `List<Number>`, then just have that as return type. Frankly speaking, I don't see any use of generic method here.

Comment: whoops. It should be S extends R, that was a typo that got copy-pasted.

Comment: the `List<Number>` part is just an example. I want it to be able to mix any two types. A trivial implementation of `mix` could be just `ArrayList<R> result = new ArrayList<>(ts.size() + ss.size()); result.addAll(ts); result.addAll(ss); return result;`

Comment: R is intended to be some superclass common to T and S. For a Double and an Integer, it could be Number. For a StringBuilder and a String, it could be CharSequence. For a Scanner and a Comparator, it could be Object.

Comment: `<R super T, S extends R> List<R>` is really the signature that would make sense. Related post: [Bounding generics with 'super' keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800369/bounding-generics-with-super-keyword). You may have to settle for keeping it a static method.

Comment: +1 This is a good one. I don't think there is a way to do this. Unless you declare the relationship of `T` against `R` in the declartion of the type `List2`. Which would simply be moving the type parameters in the method declaration to the class declartion: `class List2<R, T extends R, S extends R>`, which I assume is not what you wanted.

Comment: @PaulBellora. `R super T` is not supported.

Comment: @RohitJain Yes, I know that. Please read my entire comment.

Answer (score 8):

As noted in the question and in the comments, the following signature would be ideal:

```
<R super T, S extends R> List<R> mix(List<S> otherList)
```

But of course, `R super T` [is not allowed by the language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800369/bounding-generics-with-super-keyword) (note that polygenelubricants's answer on the linked post is wrong - there are use cases for this syntax, as your question demonstrates).

There's no way to win here - you only have one of several workarounds to choose from:

- Resort to using a signature with raw types. Don't do this.
- Keep `mix` a static method. This is actually a decent option, unless it needs to be part of your class's interface for polymorphism-related reasons, or you plan for `mix` to be such a commonly used method that you think keeping it static is unnacceptable.
- Settle with the signature of `mix` being overly restrictive, and document that certain unchecked casts will be necessary on the part of the caller. This is similar to what [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s [`Optional.or`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html#or%28T%29) had to do. From that method's documentation:

> Note about generics: The signature `public T or(T defaultValue)` is overly restrictive. However, the ideal signature, `public <S super T> S or(S)`, is not legal Java. As a result, some sensible operations involving subtypes are compile errors:
>
> ```
> Optional<Integer> optionalInt = getSomeOptionalInt();
> Number value = optionalInt.or(0.5); // error
> ```
>
> As a workaround, it is always safe to cast an `Optional<? extends T>` to `Optional<T>`. Casting [the above `Optional` instance] to `Optional<Number>` (where `Number` is the desired output type) solves the problem:
>
> ```
> Optional<Number> optionalInt = (Optional) getSomeOptionalInt();
> Number value = optionalInt.or(0.5); // fine
> ```

Unfortunately for you, it's *not* always safe to cast `List2<? extends T>` to `List2<T>`. For example, casting a `List2<Integer>` to a `List2<Number>` could permit a `Double` to be added to something that was only supposed to hold `Integer`s and lead to unexpected runtime errors. The exception would be if `List2` was immutable (like `Optional`), but this seems unlikely.

Still, you could get away with such casts if you were careful and documented type-unsafe code with explanations. Assuming `mix` had the following signature (and implementation, for fun):

```
List<T> mix(final List<? extends T> otherList) {

    final int totalElements = (size() + otherList.size());
    final List<T> result = new ArrayList<>(totalElements);

    Iterator<? extends T> itr1 = iterator();
    Iterator<? extends T> itr2 = otherList.iterator();
    while (result.size() < totalElements) {
        final T next = (itr1.hasNext() ? itr1 : itr2).next();
        result.add(next);
        final Iterator<? extends T> temp = itr1;
        itr1 = itr2;
        itr2 = temp;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Then you might have the following call site:

```
final List2<Integer> ints = new List2<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
final List<Double> doubles = Arrays.asList(1.5, 2.5, 3.5);

final List<Number> mixed;
// type-unsafe code within this scope
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // okay because intsAsNumbers isn't written to
    final List2<Number> intsAsNumbers = (List2<Number>)(List2<?>)ints;
    mixed = intsAsNumbers.mix(doubles);
}

System.out.println(mixed); // [1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5]
```

Again, a settling for a static `mix` is going to be cleaner and have no risk to type-safety. I would make sure to have very good reasons not to keep it that way.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I'm not sure in your question is whether you already know of which supertype these subclasses extends, or you want a completely generic method where you'd pass two subtypes of any given superclass.

In the first case, I did something similar recently, with an Abstract Class and several subtypes:

```
public <V extends Superclass> List<Superclass> mix(List<V> list1, List<V> list2) {
  List<Superclass> mixedList;

  mixedList.addAll(list1);
  mixedList.addAll(list2);
}
```

The latter case is much more complicated. I'd suggest you rethink your design, since it makes much more sense for the mix method to be in the Superclass or in a class which knows the superclass and its subtypes, since you're returning a List of the Superclass.

If you really want to do this, you would have to refactor List2 to List2 and do the following:

```
public <R, V extends R> List<R> mix(List<V> list1, List<V> list2) {
    List<R> mixedList;

    mixedList.addAll(list1);
    mixedList.addAll(list2);

    return mixedList;
}
```