# Declaring the return value of a method as the common supertype

Tags: java, generics

Suppose I have three types, `S`, `T`, and `U` where S is the most specific common supertype of `T` and `U`. I could let the user declare this explicitly:

```
class Foo<S, T extends S, U extends S>
{
    public S choose(T t, U u);  // chooses either t or u based on some criteria

    ...
}
```

Is there any way to infer S automatically?

```
class Foo<T, U>
{
    public ???? choose(T t, U u);  // chooses either t or u based on some criteria

    ...
}
```

Comment: similar but not the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18303724/use-generic-to-store-common-supertype-in-java

Answer (score 1):

Try a generic method instead of a generic class.

```
public class Main {
    static final Random random = new Random();

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Bar bar = choose(new Baz(), new Qux());
    }

    public static <S, T extends S, U extends S> S choose(T one, U two) {
        return random.nextBoolean() ? one : two;
    }

    interface Foo{}
    interface Bar extends Foo{}
    static class Baz implements Bar{}
    static class Qux implements Bar{}
}
```

Comment: How is that better?

Comment: The client doesn't have to declare the generic types when instantiating the class (obviously the static is just for convenience; it could be an instance method).

Comment: The applicability of this is very limited, though. There is likely a *reason* for the *class* being parameterized with `T` and `U`. The parameters in the method are totally unrelated to that of the class. A workaround would be to let `choose` just return `Object` and wrap the call into a `<S, T extends S, U extends S> S call(Foo<T, U> c, T t, U u) { return (S)c.choose(t, u); }`, with an (unchecked but safe) cast, but it's very unlikely that this is a reasonable solution either... :-/