# Java: Syntax of ClassA<T super ClassB>

Tags: java, generics

I'm learning Java generics type and I saw some syntax like `<? super T>`, `<? extends T>` and `<T extends SomeClass>`.

If:

```
public class MyClass<T extends Number> {}
```

means MyClass can be constructed only with a generic type that is the subclass of Number,

what would be the correct syntax for declaring a class that only accepts Number and its superclass as its generic type, like:

```
//public class MyClass<T super Number> {}
```

Comment: Please see the linked question and its answers for why this does not make sense.

Comment: @MiserableVariable Actually I'm critical of that accepted answer and become sad whenever more people upvote it. But yes, lower bounds don't make sense on *class*-level type parameters.

Comment: @PaulBellora can elaborate why you don't like that answer? I found the explanation under non-array type adequate. Can you also describe where lower bounds may make sense?

Comment: @MiserableVariable Sorry I didn't quite get that... According  to the best answer of that question, he is trying to prove that creating a method that only accepts Integer, Number, and Object is impossible... But I do feel it is kind of possible if you put it in any Collection types.. like "public void method(ArrayList<? super Integer> arg){}", this method actually does accept only ArrayList<Integer>, ArrayList<Number>, and ArrayList<Object>, even if String is Object...

Comment: @MiserableVariable See the comments under that answer and [Rotsor's counterexample answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5671079/697449).