# Safe workaround for broken contravariant bounds in Java?

Tags: java, generics

As discussed in [Bounding generics with 'super' keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800369/bounding-generics-with-super-keyword) the Java type system is broken/incomplete when it comes to lower bounds on method generics.  Since Optional is now part of the JDK, I'm starting to use it more and the problems that Guava encountered with their Optional are starting to become a pain for me.  I came up with a decent work around, but I'm not sure its safe.  First, let me setup the example:

```
public class A {}
public class B extends A {}
```

I would like to be able to declare a method like:

```
public class Cache {
   private final Map<String, B> cache;
   public <T super B> Optional<T> find(String s) {
       return Optional<T>.ofNullable(cache.get(s));
   }
}
```

So that both of the following work:

```
A a = cache.find("A").orElse(new A())
B b = cache.find("B").orElse(new B())
```

As a workaround, I have a static utility method as follows:

```
public static <S, T extends S> Optional<S> convertOptional(Optional<T> optional) {
    return (Optional<S>)optional;
}
```

So my final question, is this as type-safe as the 'ideal' code above?

```
A a = OptionalUtil.<A,B>convertOptional(cache.find("A")).orElse(new A());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're effectively trying to view the `Optional<B>` returned as an `Optional<A>` without changing the return type (since you can't use the `super`). I would just [`map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) the [identity function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#identity--).

```
A a = cache.find("A").map(Function.<A> identity()).orElse(new A());
// or shorter
A a = cache.find("A").<A> map(x -> x).orElse(new A());
```

I don't see anything wrong with your approach though.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your code is type safe because you are casting `Optional<T>` to `Optional<S>`, and T is always an S. You can indicate this to the compiler by using the `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` annotation on your convertOptional utility method.

As well as the other excellent answer, you could do it this way. Note the lack of generics compared to your first version.

```
package com.company;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class Cache {
    private static final Function<A,A> CAST_TO_A = Function.<A>identity();
    private final Map<String, B> cache = new HashMap<>();

    public Optional<B> find(String s) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(cache.get(s));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cache cache = new Cache();

        Optional<B> potentialA = cache.find("A");

        A a = potentialA.isPresent() ? potentialA.get() : new A();

        A anotherWay = cache.find("A").map(CAST_TO_A).orElse(new A());

        B b = cache.find("B").orElse(new B());
    }

    public static class A {}
    public static class B extends A {}
}
```

Comment: Using a ternary is a bit less elegant though, especially in long expressions

Comment: One man's inelegance is another man's clarity. One man's elegance is another man's unecessary lambda. Personally, while favouring lambda's for this kind of thing, I find the need to specify <A> for the <A>map(x -> x) inelegant. (I like the lambda solution by the way, which is why I described it as excellent)

Comment: I was not comparing to the other answer, but to the syntax of a perfect world. We would like to handle all the cases in the same way, or as close as possible. Anyway, I was just commenting :p Your answer works at least

Comment: Fair enough. I tried to see if it was possible to make the syntax perfect by making changes to java.util.Optional::orElse signature but I ran into the problem discussed in the author's first link. Incorporated your comment into the answer after admitting defeat!

Answer (score 1):

In practice, I think it is type-safe, because the `Optional` class is immutable and T is subtype of S.

Beware though that `T is subtype of S` does **NOT** mean that `Optional<T> is subtype of Optional<S>`, so theoretically that cast is not correct. And in some cases, it is not safe to do such kind of casts and it can be problematic at run-time (as it happens with [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/subtype.html)).

So my suggestion is to avoid casts whenever we can, and I would rather define a method like the `getOrElse`. Also, for the sake of completeness, the generic types in your method `convertOptional` could be simplified as below.

```
class OptionalUtil {
    public static <S> S getOrElse(Optional<? extends S> optional, Supplier<? extends S> other) {
        return optional.map(Function.<S>identity()).orElseGet(other);
    }

    public static <S> Optional<S> convertOptional(Optional<? extends S> optional) {
        return (Optional<S>)optional;
    }
}
```

And they could be use like that:

```
A a1 = OptionalUtil.getOrElse(cache.find("A"), A::new);
A a2 = OptionalUtil.<A>convertOptional(cache.find("A")).orElseGet(A::new);
```

---

**[EDIT]** I replaced the method `orElse` by `orElseGet`, because with the former a new `A` object will be created even if the `Optional` is present.

Comment: Interestingly, the getOrElse is exactly what I ended up doing.  I too hate casts.