# What's wrong with the "super" keyword in Java generic type

Tags: java, super, generic-type-argument

I encountered a strange problem in my project. Now I have simplified the problem and written a small example here to illustrate my confusion:

```
public class Question {
    class Q1 {}

    class Q2 extends Q1 {}

    interface In<T> {
        void f(T t);
    }

    List<Q2> list;

    void f(In<? super List<? super Q2>> in) {
        in.f(list);
    }

    static void g() {
        Question question = new Question();
        In<Collection<Q1>> in1 = new In<Collection<Q1>>() {
            @Override
            public void f(Collection<Q1> o) {}
        };
        In<List<Q2>> in2 = new In<List<Q2>>() {
            @Override
            public void f(List<Q2> o) {}
        };
        question.f(in1); //Error!
        question.f(in2); //Error!
    }
}
```

My aim is to make the method `f(In<? super List<? super Q2>>)` more flexible. I can pass `in1` or `in2` to the method. But neither can be passed! What is wrong?

Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800369/bounding-generics-with-super-keyword) will make some sense. But my question is different!!! My generic type is `In<? super List<? super Q2>>`, a generic type within a generic type.

Comment: @AndyTurner " everything matches ? super Q2"  so why `question.f(in1)` is error? can you clear more?

Comment: @Jerry06 I think I misinterpreted the question. Reopened.

Answer (score 2):

A generic type of the form `A<? extends B>` means that the `?` can be replaced by `B` or any super-type of `B`. Thus, `List<? super Q2>` means something like: either `List<Object>`, `List<Q1>` or `List<Q2>`.

Although `Q1` is a super-type of `Q2`, `List<Q1>` is not a super-type of `List<Q2>`. This means that the only common super-type of `List<Object>`, `List<Q1>` and `List<Q2>` is `Object`. So the only thing you can pass to your `f` method is an `In<Object>`.

How you need to solve this is dependent on what flexibility you actually need: what kind of objects do you want to pass to `f` and what do want to do with those objects?

Comment: What about `<? extends List<? extends Q1>>`? And What should I do if I want to pass any subclass of `Collection` to `f`?

Answer (score 0):

```
In<Collection<? extends Q1>> in1 = new In<Collection<? extends Q1>>() {
            @Override
            public void f(Collection<? extends Q1> o) {}
        };
        In<List<? extends Q2>> in2 = new In<List<? extends Q2>>() {
            @Override
            public void f(List<? extends Q2> o) {}
        };
```

Comment: `extend` is different. It is easier. Please change it into `super` and see what happens.