# Why is there no Instance-level Stream.concat method in Java?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I know that `Stream.concat` exists ([doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#concat-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-)) to concatenate two streams. However, I have run into cases where I need to add "a few more" items to an existing stream, and then continue processing on it. In such a situation, I would have expected to be able to chain together methods like:

```
getStream(someArg)
  .map(Arg::getFoo)
  .concat(someOtherStreamOfFoos) // Or append, or...
  .map(...)
```

However, no such instance-level chainable `append/concat` method exists.

This isn't a question asking for solutions to this problem, or more elegant approaches (although I would of course be grateful for any other viewpoints!). Rather, I'm asking about the design factors that led to this decision. The Stream interface was, I trust, designed by some extremely smart people who are aware of the [Principle of Least Astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) - so, I must assume that their decision to omit this (to me) intuitively-obvious method signifies either that the method is an antipattern, or that it is not possible due to some technical limitation. I'd love to know the reason.

Comment: It's a good question but I am trying to think of a case where making it an instance method is any better than it being `static`. for example, the code snippet you've shown can also be written as `Stream.concat(getStream(someArg).map(Arg::getFoo), someOtherStreamOfFoos).map(...)`

Comment: I suspect it wouldn't have worked well with the type system.

Comment: @Aominè - agreed, the effectively-same functionality is definitely still available by the existing methods. My argument is more for readability - "reading down" a Stream pipeline, with sequential filter/map/reduce operations, is much more intuitive to me than having to jump "back up" a few lines (after noticing an extra close-paren) to identify a `concat` that was declared higher up.

Comment: It's a good question. Maybe the comment `Use caution when constructing streams from repeated concatenation` is part of it. If it were a fluent API you may be tempted to concatenate repeatedly, whereas forcing you to do e.g. `concat(s1, concat(s2, s3))` makes people less likely to do it?

Comment: I found the changeset that moves concat to a static method: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2012-November/006887.html but no comments as to why seem to be given. Neither here: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8015315

Comment: I guess `Stream`'s pipeline implementation is complicated enough as to allow more than one source for the elements. I also don't know how parallelism would play in this situation. StreamEx library has `append` and `prepend` methods, so it's doable. I'm not aware of the complexities, though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I can give you one reason it wouldn't have worked.

`Stream.concat` is defined as

```
static <T> Stream<T> concat(Stream<? extends T> a,
                            Stream<? extends T> b)
```

You can `concat` a `Stream<HashMap>` and `Stream<Map>` into a `Stream<Map>`, or even `concat` a `Stream<HashMap>` and a `Stream<TreeMap>` into a `Stream<Map>`. To do that with an instance method, you would need to be able to declare a type parameter like `<U super T>`, which Java doesn't allow.

```
// It'd look kind of like this, if Java allowed it.
public <U super T> Stream<U> concat(Stream<? extends U> other)
```

Java only allows upper-bounded type parameters, not lower-bounded.

Concatenating a `Stream<Something>` and a `Stream<SomethingElse>` might seem unusual, but type inference often produces type parameters too specific to work with an instance method. For example,

```
Stream.concat(Stream.of(dog), animalStream)
```

which would require an explicit type parameter if written as

```
Stream.<Animal>of(dog).concat(animalStream)
```

Comment: I think returning the same generic type would still be useful in most cases, like when the two streams have the same type. They could keep the less-convenient static version for the rare cases. Also, for anyone wondering _why_ `<U super T>` isn't valid Java, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33895470/2643425

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this would be possible with the chaining method as described in https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8140283? It would then alleviate the readability problem.

Comment: This is true, but in practice it wouldn't have mattered. If the signature had been `Stream<T> concat(Stream<? extends T> other)`, that would have been ok for most cases. For the rare cases when you really did want to concatenate a `Stream<Integer>` and a `Stream<Double>` you could just have done `integerStream.map(a -> (Number) a).concat(doubleStream)`

Comment: @PaulBoddington: I suspect it would matter more for cases where the first argument also needs type inference, like `Stream.concat(Stream.of(dog), animalStream)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is just missed functionality of Stream API.

Note that RxJava's Observable has method "concatWith" with required functionality, so your question is reasonable:

```
Observable<String> o1 = ...;
Observable<Integer> o2 = ...;
o1.map(s -> s.length())
  .concatWith(o2)
  ....
```

Java 8 has another functionality is nice to have is get another Optional if current Optional is empty, like:

```
Optional.ofNullable(x).orElse(anotherOptional)
```

What I want to say that this concat you described is possible, just not implemented in the `Stream`.

Comment: the use of `orElse(anotherOptional)` is wrong. Either it should be `orElse(aValue)` or the java9 introduced `or(anotherOptional)`