# Restrict generic types to super types on a method

Tags: java, generics

I have a list decorator that should, amongst a lot of other things, allow casting from one list to another. The idea is like that, and it already works:

```
public class ExtendedList<T> implements List<T> {

    private List<T> delegate;

    // constructors, methods, a collector, etc

    public <R> ExtendedList<R> castTo(Class<R> targetType) {
        return delegate.stream().map(item -> (R) item).collect(ExtendedList.toList());
    }
}
```

I wonder if (and how) it is possible to restrict type parameter `R` to valid casting targets like `T`, all superclasses of `T` and all interfaces that `T` implements, so that the compiler can already check if casting is possible when I use it:

```
ExtendedList<Vehicle> vehicles = cars.castTo(Vehicle.class);  // assuming Car implements Vehicle -> OK
ExtendedList<Dog> dogs = cars.castTo(Dog.class);              // assuming Car does not extend Dog -> not OK
```

Comment: I can't test this at the moment, but does `public <R super T>` not work?

Comment: Do you also want to allow `vehicles.castTo(Car.class)`?

Comment: @Sweeper no, that shouldn't work. Not every `Vehicle` is a `Car` so it would be OK for my method to not allow that.

Comment: @JacobG. `<R super T>` emits Unexpected Token errors. That's obviously no valid syntax. Was my first idea also.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800369/bounding-generics-with-super-keyword). The conclusion seems to be "it's not useful"...

Comment: In case you didn't know, streaming the elements one by one and casting them individually is pointless. [It will succeed](https://ideone.com/0SNs48) even if the elements do not match (the cast to `R` is erased to `Object` -- everything succeeds). You may as well just do `return (ExtendedList<R>) delegate`. That is, unless you care about getting a copy of the list, but even in that case there are more concise ways to accomplish that than what you've written.

Comment: `(R) item` does nothing and in fact generates a compiler warning that tells you this, because at runtime there is no `R`.  Use `targetType.cast(item)` instead.

Comment: @Michael Yes, it's pointless, from a technical perspective, but nevertheless, I have cases in the code where I get a `List<Car>` from somewhere and need to use that on a function that requires `List<Vehicle>`. I can use raw types or waste CPU time to create a copy of the list with where all items have the expected type... That annoys me since Java 5 introduced the generics.

Comment: "*to create a copy of the list with where all items have the expected type*" You missed my point. Your code does not *ensure* anything. It just copies elements from `List<Object>` to another, paying no attention to the types of the elements, and it does so inefficiently one at a time. See @VGR's point

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks for closing - the other question is not related to my question and does not answer it at all. Please pay more attention to that, when you vote for closing. I asked for a solution to my problem and not for an explanation why something we talked in the comments about does not work.

Comment: @Andreas_D [An answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5671079/5133585) to the dupe target showed the same solution as the accepted answer here i.e. a static method. Therefore, I concluded that this question is a duplicate and closed. I do apologise for forgetting to point out which answer in the dupe target answered your question.

Comment: @Sweeper We close questions if the question is a duplicate, not if a possible answer can be found on another question that asked something different. Nevertheless, Artyer gave an answer and I can continue with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a static method:

```java
public <R> ExtendedList<R> castToUnchecked() {
    return delegate.stream().map(item -> (R) item).collect(ExtendedList.toList());
}

public static <R, U extends R> ExtendedList<R> castTo(ExtendedList<U> l) {
    return l.<R>castToUnchecked();
}
```

Which ensures that `R` is a superclass of `U`, used as:

```java
ExtendedList<Vehicle> vehicles = ExtendedList.<Vehicle>castTo(cars);
ExtendedList<Dog> dogs = ExtendedList.<Dog>castTo(cars);  // error: `Car` doesn't extend `Dog`
```

Comment: Thanks! That works with one exception: I have to give 2 type parameters when I use the function, like: `ExtendedList.<Vehicle, Car>castTo(cars)`, otherwise the compiler is unhappy. Should it work with just one, the target type?