# Java Map.getOrDefault with bounded wildcard

Tags: java, generics

Got a `Map<String, ? extends Map<String, Integer>> mapOfMaps` variable.

```java
Map<String, Integer> result = mapOfMaps.get("aaa");
```

works, but

```java
Map<String, Integer> result = mapOfMaps.getOrDefault("aaa",Collections.emptyMap());
```

says

> The method getOrDefault(Object, capture#1-of ? extends Map<String,Integer>) in the type Map<String,capture#1-of ? extends Map<String,Integer>> is not applicable for the arguments (String, Map<String,Integer>)

the same goes for

```java
Map<String, Integer> result = mapOfMaps.getOrDefault("aaa",Collections.<String,Integer>emptyMap());
```

or

```java
Map<String, Integer> result = mapOfMaps.getOrDefault("aaa",(Map<String,Integer>)Collections.EMPTY_MAP);
```

or even

```java
Map<String, Integer> result = mapOfMaps.getOrDefault("aaa",new HashMap<String, Integer>());
```

---

Is there a way of using the getOrDefault like that or do I have to use the clunky way ?

```java
Map<String, Integer> result = mapOfMaps.get("aaa");
if( result == null ) {
  result = Collections.emptyMap();
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a `Map<String, ? extends Map<String, Integer>>` and not a `Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>` anyways?

Comment: It's a function parameter and it is called with `TreeMap<String,TreeMap<String,Integer>>`

Comment: I know what it is but why do you need it? Why can't you use a `Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>` and fill it with `TreeMap`s?

Comment: the `TreeMap<String,TreeMap<String,Integer>>` ? All of the other code needs a TreeMap.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2800369/1553851

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Collections.unmodifiableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableMap-java.util.Map-) to view your map as `Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>`.

```
Map<String, ? extends Map<String, Integer>> mapOfMaps = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> view = Collections.unmodifiableMap(mapOfMaps);
Map<String, Integer> map = view.getOrDefault("foo", Collections.emptyMap());
```

In a single line, however, it still looks ugly, since you need to specify the generic type arguments for `unmodifiableMap`.

```
Map<String, Integer> map = Collections.<String, Map<String, Integer>>
    unmodifiableMap(mapOfMaps).getOrDefault("foo", Collections.emptyMap());
```

#### Explanation

You cannot call any method that has an unbounded or `extends`-bounded wildcard parameter, because the exact type of the wildcard is not known at compile time.

Let's make this simpler and look at `Map<String, ? extends Number>`, to which you could assign either of

```
Map<String, ? extends Number> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
Map<String, ? extends Number> map = new HashMap<String, Double>();
```

However, when calling `map.getOrDefault(Object k, V defaultValue)`, there is no way to determine the type for `defaultValue` at compile time, since the actual type may change at runtime, even for the very same assignment (not the same instance though).

```
// compile-time error, could require a Double or any other Number-type
Number i = map.getOrDefault("foo", (Number)Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

Comment: I like this solution better, because I can simply call my function like `fn(Collections.unmodifiableMap(mapOfMaps))` and inside then use just the plain ol' `getOrDefault`

Comment: @Yes, that indirectly specifies the generic type parameters for `unmodifiableMap`, too, similar to how I did it through an assignment in the first example.

Answer (score 0):

One possible, but still rather clunky, solution is a helper function:

```java
static <K1, K2, V, M extends Map<K2, V>> Map<K2, V> getOrEmpty(Map<K1, M> mapOfMaps, K1 key) {
  Map<K2, V> submap = mapOfMaps.get(key);
  return submap != null ? submap : Collections.emptyMap();
}
```

and then call it like

```java
Map<String, Integer> result = getOrEmpty(mapOfMaps,"aaa");
```

---

But I would still prefer a solution without having to define an extra function.