# Java multiple generic collection parameters compile error

Tags: java, generics, collections, compiler-errors

So strange! Please have a look the code first:

```
public class A {}

public class B extends A {}

public class C extends A {}

public class TestMain {

    public <T extends A> void test(T a, T b) {}

    public <T extends A> void test(List<T> a, List<T> b) {}

    public void test1(List<? extends A> a, List<? extends A> b) {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestMain().test(new B(), new C());
        new TestMain().test(new ArrayList<C>(), new ArrayList<C>());
        new TestMain().test(new ArrayList<B>(), new ArrayList<C>());
        new TestMain().test1(new ArrayList<B>(), new ArrayList<C>());
    }
}
```

The statement `new TestMain().test(new ArrayList<B>(), new ArrayList<C>())` gets a compilation error:

> Bound mismatch: The generic method test(T, T) of type TestMain is not applicable
>    for the arguments `(ArrayList<B>, ArrayList<C>)`. The inferred type
>    `ArrayList<? extends A>` is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter
>    `<T extends A>`

However:

```
 new TestMain().test(new B(), new C())  --> compiled ok

 new TestMain().test(new ArrayList<C>(), new ArrayList<C>()) --> compiled ok

 new TestMain().test1(new ArrayList<B>(), new ArrayList<C>()) --> compiled ok
```

If we define the generic before the method name, it seems the type of the second generic `List` parameter must be the same as that of the first. But there is no restriction if we define generic in parameters.

Is it a feature or a bug of the compile program? Is there some documentation about it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is absolutely no bug; you simply misunderstood the subtyping rules in generics.

Since we have `B extends A`:

- `B` is a subtype of `A`
- an `instanceof B` is also an `instanceof A`

Since Java arrays are covariant:

- `B[]` is a subtype of `A[]`
- an `instanceof B[]` is also an `instanceof A[]`

However, Java generics are invariant:

- `List<B>` is NOT a subtype of `List<A>`
- a `instanceof List<B>` is NOT an `instanceof List<A>`.

When you have the following generic method declaration:

```
public <T extends A> void test(List<T> a, List<T> b)
```

Then, as it's explicitly stated here, `a` and `b` must both have the same type, `List<T>`, for some capture conversion of type parameter `<T extends A>`.

Since `List<B>` and `List<C>` are two different types, you can't mix them as actual arguments for `test`. Also, even though `B` and `C` are subtypes of `A`, generics are invariant, so neither `List<B>` nor `List<C>` is a `List<A>`.

Thus,

```
test(new ArrayList<B>(), new ArrayList<C>()); // error!!! doesn't compile!!!
```

doesn't compile, which is expected behavior.

#### See also

- [Java Tutorials/Generics](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html)

  - [Subtyping](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/generics/subtype.html)
  - [More fun with wildcards](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/generics/morefun.html)
- [JLS 10.10 Array Store Exception](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/arrays.html#10.10) and [`java.lang.ArrayStoreException`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/arrays.html#10.10)

  - Java array subtyping, being covariant, is not typesafe; generics, being invariant, is.

#### Related questions

On generics typing rules:

- [Any simple way to explain why I cannot do `List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Dog>()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346763/any-simple-way-to-explain-why-i-cannot-do-listanimal-animals-new-arraylistdo)
- [java generics (not) covariance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660827/java-generics-covariance)
- [What is a raw type and why shouldn’t we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it/)

  - Explains how raw type `List` is different from `List<Object>` which is different from a `List<?>`

On using `super` and `extends`:

- [`Java Generics: What is PECS?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs)

  - From *Effective Java 2nd Edition*: "producer `extends` consumer `super`"
- [What is the difference between `super` and `extends` in Java Generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910892/what-is-the-difference-between-super-and-extends-in-java-generics)
- [What is the difference between `<E extends Number>` and `<Number>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770264/what-is-the-difference-between-e-extends-number-and-number/)
- [How can I add to `List<? extends Number>` data structures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776975/how-can-i-add-to-list-extends-number-data-structures) (YOU CAN'T!)

On actual generic bugs:

- [Generics compiles and runs in Eclipse, but doesn’t compile in javac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858799/generics-compiles-and-runs-in-eclipse-but-doesnt-compile-in-javac)

Answer (score 9):

It's not a bug, it's just that generics are complex. Try changing your second test method to:

```
    public <T extends A, K extends A> void test(List<T> a, List<K> b) {
```

Basically in what you've got there is no type T that can satisfy what you're passing in, unlike the first method where B and C are just treated as A. The actual name for this behaviour escapes me but there should be plenty of examples in the literature.

In short, even though B is a child of A, List<B> is not a child of List<A>.