# What's the purpose behind wildcards and how are they different from generics?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I'd never heard about wildcars until a few days ago and after reading my teacher's Java book, I'm still not sure about what's it for and why would I need to use it.

Let's say I have a super class `Animal` and few sub classes like `Dog`, `Cat`, `Parrot`, etc... Now I need to have a list of animals, my first thought would be something like:

```
List<Animal> listAnimals
```

Instead, my colleagues are recommending something like:

```
List<? extends Animal> listAnimals
```

Why should I use wildcards instead of simple generics?

Let's say I need to have a get/set method, should I use the former or the later? How are they so different?

Comment: I would highly recommend Bloch's "Effective Java" for an in-depth discussion of this topic.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The wildcards do not make a lot of sense when you declare local variables, however they are really important when you declare a parameter for a method.

Imagine you have a method:

```
int countLegs ( List< ? extends Animal > animals )
{
   int retVal = 0;
   for ( Animal cur : animals )
   {
      retVal += cur.countLegs( );
   }

   return retVal;
}
```

With this signature you can do this:

```
List<Dog> dogs = ...;
countLegs( dogs );

List<Cat> cats = ...;
countLegs( cats );

List<Animal> zoo = ...;
countLegs( zoo );
```

If, however, you declare `countLegs` like this:

```
int countLegs ( List< Animal > animals )
```

Then in the previous example only `countLegs( zoo )` would have compiled, because only that call has a correct type.

Comment: @Nazgulled. As a corollary, for instance and local variables I recommend to always try to use a non-wildcarded generic.  Sometimes you just don't have a choice, for example if the wildcarded generic is passed in the constructor and you need to store that reference, that's what you do.  But if you are creating a generic variable, always try to assign it to non-wildcard declaration.  You can always convert it to a wildcard later, but not otherwise without "unchecked" warning.

Answer (score 25):

Java generics are invariant.

Suppose we have `B extends A`:

- `B` is a subtype of `A`
- an `instanceof B` is also an `instanceof A`

Since Java arrays are covariant:

- `B[]` is a subtype of `A[]`
- an `instanceof B[]` is also an `instanceof A[]`

However, Java generics are invariant:

- `List<B>` is NOT a subtype of `List<A>`
- a `instanceof List<B>` is NOT an `instanceof List<A>`.

Wildcards are used to make it more flexible while preserving type safety.

- a `List<B>` is a `List<? extends A>`

#### References

- [Java Tutorials/Generics](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html)

  - [Subtyping](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/generics/subtype.html)
  - [More fun with wildcards](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/generics/morefun.html)

#### Related questions

- [Any simple way to explain why I cannot do `List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Dog>()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346763/any-simple-way-to-explain-why-i-cannot-do-listanimal-animals-new-arraylistdo)
- [java generics (not) covariance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660827/java-generics-covariance)
- [What is the difference between `<E extends Number>` and `<Number>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770264/what-is-the-difference-between-e-extends-number-and-number/)

Answer (score 10):

The difference between your 2 examples is simply that the first one is a list of generic/general animals - you can therefore add any type of animal to it, and any instance of a subclass of type Animal. (e.g. It can contain some dogs, some cats, some porcupines...) Whereas the second - `List <? extends Animal>` - will be a list of *one specific subtype* of class animal. It can be any one you choose (this is set each time at runtime), but only one. It will *either* be a list of dogs, *or* a list of cats, *or* a list of turtles... etc.

Comment: +1 I thought it was the other way around, but it makes sense. Is like saying: *"This would be a list of  I don't know what ( ? ) which is a subclass of Animal"*  The question that comes later is, would it still be possible to declare it as: `List<Animal>` ? Or could I use a subclass of the subclass i.e. `List<Dog> l; l.add(new Bulldog() )`

Comment: -1. List< ? extends Animal > can definitely be List< Animal >.  The difference, you can only `get` Animals out of it and not put them back.  The list itself still can contain a zoo ( or a farm ).

Comment: @Alexander Pogrebnyak - If you cannot "put" (as in "put them back") Animals into List<? extends Animal> then how do you ever do anything useful with the list?

Comment: @Buttons840.  You still can iterate through the values and remove them.  In many cases that's all the functionality required.

Answer (score 2):

You can store Dogs and Cats in a `List<Animal>`. That is not where wildcards are needed.

Let's say you have a method that takes a list of animals:

```
void foo(List<Animal> animals) {
    ...
}
```

Now you can't pass the method a List of Dogs -- it only takes an argument of type `List<Animal>`. You need a wildcard to make the method accept all kinds of Lists of Animals: `List<Animal>`, `List<Dog>`, `List<Cat>`, ...

```
void foo(List<? extends Animal> animals) {
    ...
}
```

See

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html