# in Java syntax, Class<? extends Something>

Tags: java, generics

`Class<? extends Something>`

Here's my interpretation, it's class template but the class ? means the name of the class is undetermined and it extends the Something class.

if there's something wrong with my interpretation, let me know.

Comment: the ? means the `type` of the class is undetermined, but you are guaranteed that is extends `Something`

Comment: yep.  refer to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the purpose behind wildcards and how are they different from generics?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922811/whats-the-purpose-behind-wildcards-and-how-are-they-different-from-generics)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You are almost right. 
Basically, Java has no concept of templates (C++ has).
This is called generics.
And this defines a generic class `Class<>` with the generics' attribute being any subclass of `Something`.

I suggest reading up "[What are the differences between “generic” types in C++ and Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36347/what-are-the-differences-between-generic-types-in-c-and-java)" if you want to get the difference between templates and generics.

Answer (score 53):

There are a few confusing answers here so I will try and clear this up.
You define a generic as such:

```
public class Foo<T> {
    private T t;
    public void setValue(T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }
    public T getValue() {
        return t;
    }
}
```

If you want a generic on Foo to always extend a class Bar you would declare it as such:

```
public class Foo<T extends Bar> {
    private T t;
    public void setValue(T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }
    public T getValue() {
        return t;
    }
}
```

The `?` is used when you declare a variable.

```
Foo<? extends Bar>foo = getFoo();
```

OR

```
DoSomething(List<? extends Bar> listOfBarObjects) {
    //internals
}
```

Comment: Based on your explanation a question comes to mind. What would have been the difference between declaring the variable that way and using the Bar class directly? As far as I understand, any object from a class inheriting from Bar would have had the same behavior. Am I missing something? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Answering my own question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922811/whats-the-purpose-behind-wildcards-and-how-are-they-different-from-generics

Comment: Wait - I think the original poster was specifically asking about the Class type.

Answer (score 10):

You're right

Definition is that the class has to be subtype of Something

It's the same as `Class<T>`, but there is a condition that `T` must `extends Something`
Or `implements Something` as Anthony Accioly suggested

It can also be class `Something` itself

Comment: Or implement `Something` interface... When dealing with generics "extends" is used for both.

Answer (score 9):

You're correct.

In Java generics, the `?` operator means "any class". The `extends` keyword may be used to qualify that to "any class which extends/implements `Something` (or **is** `Something`).

Thus you have "the `Class` of some class, but that class must be or extend/implement `Something`".

Comment: The `?` is technically not an *operator* here.

Comment: @Jesper: true - I was using *operator* as a figure of speech, but I guess *wildcard* might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

You're correct.

However usually you will want to name the class that extends Something and write e.g. `<E extends Something>`. If you use `?` you can't do anything with the given type later.