# Instantiating a Generic Class of Type <?>

Tags: java, generics, collections, scjp, ocpjp

I'm studying for the SCJP/OCPJP and I came across a sample question that seams strange to me.

The sample code instantiated two generic collections:

```
List<?> list = new ArrayList<?>();
List<? extends Object> list2 = new ArrayList<? extends Object>();
```

The "correct" answer to the question was that this code would compile but adding to either collection would produce a runtime error.

When I try to compile code like this I just get errors. The Java tutorial does not even show this type of code, it instead usually uses wildcards as a part of an upcast.

```
Collection<?> c = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Are the two generic collections above even legitimate code? The second by my logic would only disallow interfaces. The first one looks completely useless. Why use a generic that makes no attempt at control?

Comment: Don't see how this would compile AND you can add to both collections just fine - just only exactly ONE object. I leave it as an exercise for the reader to figure out which object is valid for every class :)

Comment: You can't do either. I wanted to find out if the sample question/answer was wrong and apparently it is.

Comment: Down voted just now for what reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the excellent [Java generics tutorial PDF](http://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=java%20generics%20tutorial%20pdf&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fjava.sun.com%2Fj2se%2F1.5%2Fpdf%2Fgenerics-tutorial.pdf&ei=GRL-TqzQCcPqOczhwacB&usg=AFQjCNHlDA-kbX-h4ixgUmBJK6VZNRVENw&cad=rja). More specifically the section about wildcards contains the answer to your question, and I quote

```
Collection<?> c = new ArrayList<String>();
c.add( new Object() );
```

> Since we don’t know what the element type of `c` stands for, we cannot
>   add objects to it. The `add()` method takes arguments of type `E`, the
>   element type of the collection. When the actual type parameter is `?`,
>   it stands for some unknown type. Any parameter we pass to add would
>   have to be a subtype of this unknown type. Since we don’t know what
>   type that is, we cannot pass anything in. The sole exception is `null`,
>   which is a member of every type.

Comment: That document is very useful indeed. Thank you! Do you know of any articles that good on reflection or inner classes?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to declare Type at runtime, you can do something like this:

```
public class Clazz1<T> {

private final List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();

private List<T> getList() {
    return list;
}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Clazz1<Integer> clazzInt = new Clazz1<Integer>();
    clazzInt.getList().add(2);
    System.out.println(clazzInt.getList());

    Clazz1<String> clazzString = new Clazz1<String>();
    clazzString.getList().add("test");
    System.out.println(clazzString.getList());
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I answered this somewhat before in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422842/in-java-syntax-class-extends-something/8423028#8423028) answer.  `?` cannot be used in the instantiation.   I'm not sure why it says the code would compile, none of the java compilers I have used would allow that.  You could do what is shown above by the following:

```
List<?> list = new ArrayList();
```

That would compile and run, but you couldn't do:

```
list.add("hello world"); //This wouldn't compile
```

Answer (score 0):

`new` produces a concrete instance of an object. The concrete instance can have only one type, including any generics. Knowing this, wildcards cannot work with `new`.