# Compiler warnings when declaring Generic types

Tags: java, oop, generics, scjp

Why does the compiler issue a warning when declaring a variable as

```
 List<? extends Object> list = new LinkedList();
```

Warning:

```
Note: ZiggyTest.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

But it doesnt issue a warning when i declare the variable as

```
List<?> list = new LinkedList();
```

Comment: Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683137/and-extends-object/8683314 and the excellent generics tutorial in my answer there which is a must-read when working with generics

Comment: It isn't issuing any waning as you have mentioned in my NetBeans 6.9.1 with jdk 6.

Comment: I am not using an IDE. Do you get the warnings when you compile from the command line prompt?

Comment: Yes, I tried from the *command-line* and it issued the warning as you say. When I modified your statement like `List<? extends Object> list = new LinkedList<Object>();`, it compiled with no warning. Give it a try.

Comment: I was interested in the reason as to why the warnings are generated in the first example and not in the second. I know that when i specify the type on the right and left then there wont be any warnings.

Comment: The reason has been mentioned in my following answer. ***"It means that the compiler can't check that you're using the collection in a type-safe manner."*** To avoid that warning, we should mention the exact *generic type* `<Object>` the collection is using.

Comment: It's a minor flaw in spec. `List<?>` and `List<? extends Object>` are equivalent types, but spec treats them differently sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot explain why the compiler won't treat these as equivalent, but given that it does not, I'll attempt to explain why it refuses to do so.

The first one (`List<? extends Object>`) asserts that the type of objects held in the `List` are of some unknown type derived from `Object`. The second one (`List<?>`) says less; it merely says that the type of the objects in the list is unknown. It doesn't mention any expected supertype as the upper bound of the unknown type.

In order to verify the first assumption, the compiler wants to hear you say something about the expected types held in the `List` instance constructed here as the raw type `LinkedList`, which says nothing on the subject. However, if you were to construct the instance as type `LinkedList<Object>`, you're at least guaranteeing that covariant *reads* against the instance will be consistent with your assertion: namely, that the things in this list are some kind of `Object`.

Now, this all seems silly, because every reference/non-primitive type in Java extends `Object`, so there shouldn't be any difference in interpretation between `List<? extends Object>` and `List<?>`; after all, the second one implies the first one, by virtue of the language's type system's mandated singly-rooted class hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

This comes up in Java 5 and later if you're using collections without type specifiers (e.g., `Arraylist()` instead of `ArrayList<String>()`).  It means that the compiler can't check that you're using the collection in a type-safe manner, using [generics](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/generics.html).

To get rid of the warning, just be specific about what type of objects you're storing in the collection.  So, instead of

```
List list = new ArrayList();
```

should be as

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

---

In your case, if you modify that statement as follows,

```
List<? extends Object> list = new LinkedList<Object>();
```

it would compile with no warning because we are now making it type-safe using the generic type (`<Object>`).

Comment: The `new LinkedList<? extends Object>();` does not compile