# Why Java generics allows wildcard with higher upper bound than that of type parameter's?

Tags: java, generics

This is an oversimplified version of the compiler behaviour I'm trying to understand:

```
class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HouseCat<? extends Mammal> hcat = new Tabby();
        //HouseCat<Mammal> won't work, compiler catches incorrect type parameter bound
        HouseCat<CrazyHouseCat> crazyCat = new Tabby();
    }
}

interface Mammal<T extends Mammal> extends Comparable<T>{
    T cloneInstance();
}

interface Feline<T extends Feline> extends Mammal<T>{}    

interface HouseCat <T extends HouseCat> extends Feline<T>{}

interface CrazyHouseCat<T extends CrazyHouseCat> extends HouseCat<T>{
    void pushStuffOverTvStand();
}

class Tabby implements CrazyHouseCat<CrazyHouseCat>{

    @Override
    public CrazyHouseCat cloneInstance() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void pushStuffOverTvStand() {

    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(CrazyHouseCat o) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

In the snippet above, `HouseCat<? extends Mammal>` is a reference with a wider range of types than that is allowed by the HouseCat interface, namely: `HouseCat<T extends HouseCat>`

If I were to try to do something like `HouseCat<Long>` the compiler would tell me that `Long` does not satisfy the type parameter's constraints. Well, so does not `<? extends Mammal>`, at least potentially.

The compiler would not let me create an instance that violates the type parameter `T`'s constraints but I'm confused about its behaviour regarding the use of `Mammal` as the upper bound of the reference. There is an invalid type range between (`HouseCat`,`Mammal`] so why won't the compiler refuse this reference definition?

**Clarification:**
My question is not about the meaning of wildcard `?`. I'm asking why the compiler is allowing a reference to a parameterised type instance be defined using a wider range of types than what is allowed by the parameterised type's definition. The mentioned questions do not address this specific case, they're about the meaning of a wildcard. My question is about the valid range of the wildcard, which the compiler does not seem be enforcing.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but there are many raw types in the code you posted, which is not a good idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [in Java syntax, Class<? extends Something>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422842/in-java-syntax-class-extends-something)

Comment: @SharonBenAsher I don't think so. Please see my clarification.

Comment: ` //HouseCat<Mammal> won't work, compiler catches incorrect type parameter bound` - because Mammal doesn't extend Mammal

Comment: @ACV no it won't work because Mammal is a super type of the allowed type for HouseCat's type parameter (HouseCat again). Types that extend themselves are valid type parameters in Java generics

Comment: You're right it's >=

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422842/in-java-syntax-class-extends-something) looks like it answers your question. Basically `HouseCat<? extends Mammal>` allows to create a `HouseCat<[insert type that extends Mammal here]>`. All `<? extends Mammal>` does is act as a generic. In your example I don't see why you'd try to do it this way, but I hope this helps.