# Generics method overriding 8

Tags: java, generic-programming

Why can't       `void say(List< ? extends Number> list)` be overridden by                   `void say(List< Number> list)`.

Name clash occurs when you try to compile.

Comment: In which programming language ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot override a method declared as

```
void say(List<? extends Number> list)   // A
```

with

```
void say(List<Number> list)             // B
```

simply because the types are not equivalent. For example, `List<Integer>` matches `List<? extends Number>` but not `List<Number>`, so

```
List<Integer> integers = Arrays.<Integer>asList(1, 2, 3);
a.say(integers);  // is valid assuming signature A
b.say(integers);  // does not compile
```

(see this question for details about [generics, wildcards, and type relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2922811/141081)). If the compiler did allow you to override the way you want to, then the following would be possible:

```
class A {
    void say(List<? extends Number> numbers) { }
}

class B extends A {
    void say(List<Number> numbers) { numbers.add(Double.valueOf(1.0)); }
}


List<Integer> onlyIntsPlease = new ArrayList<Integer>();
B b = new B();

// Oops! The list of `Integer` will now contain a `Double`...
b.say(onlyIntsPlease);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is impossible both on general theoretical grounds and due to the specifics of Java Generics.

The general principle is that the overriding method must be *substitutable* for the base class method. For example, the subclass method may use a *wider* access modifier, but not a *narrower* one. In your case,

```
void say(List<Number> list)
```

is more constraining than

```
void say(List<? extends Number> list)
```

so this clearly violates the substitutability principle.

A practical obstacle is this: overriding is about *runtime* polymorphism, whereas Generics are about *compile-time* polymorphism and the type parameters of the instance are not even available to the method dispatch mechanism.