# Strange behavior when overloading methods in Java

Tags: java

I came across this weird (in my opinion) behavior today. Take this simple Test class:

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test t = new Test();
    t.run();
}

private void run() {
    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
    list.add(new Object());
    list.add(new Object());
    method(list);
}

public void method(Object o) {
    System.out.println("Object");
}

public void method(List<Object> o) {
    System.out.println("List of Objects");
}
}
```

It behaves the way you expect, printing "List of Objects". But if you change the following three lines:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("");
list.add("");
```

you will get "Object" instead.

I tried this a few other ways and got the same result. Is this a bug or is it a normal behavior? And if it is normal, can someone explain why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

It's a normal behaviour. `List<String>` is not a `List<Object>`, so `method(Object)` is the only applicable method.

If `List<String>` were a `List<Object>`, you would be able to violate type safety, for example, by adding `Integer` to the `List<String>` (and it can't be caught at runtime due to type erasure):

```
public void method(List<Object> o) { 
    o.add(new Integer(10));
}
```

Also note that arrays have a different behaviour - `String[]` is an `Object[]`, because array knows its element type and throws a runtime exception if you try to put a wrong object into it.

Answer (score 6):

This is normal behaviour, because when you define a signature with generics, you specify a single class. (Unless you use [wildcards](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html), which you haven't, the link explains)...

So `List<String>` is not a `List<Object>`. It is, however a `List<? extends Object>` - give it a try and see.

Answer (score 1):

Well this is expected - the list is not of type `List<Object>`. To get the results you are expecting use:

```
public void method(List<?> o)
```

as a wild card, this will match your list.

Answer (score 0):

As expected because `List<String>` is not a `List<Object>` as stated in the other answer. To obtain the desired behavior, you need to use a wildcard:

```
public void method(List<? extends Object> o) { //or an unbounded wildcard List<?>
    System.out.println("List of Objects");
}
```

#### See also

- [Java language guide/Generics/More Fun with wildcards](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/generics/morefun.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand java generics. `List<String>` is not `List<Object>`.
[Any simple way to explain why I cannot do List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Dog>()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346763/any-simple-way-to-explain-why-i-cannot-do-listanimal-animals-new-arraylistdo)