# question about interfaces and generics in Java: type mismatch error

Tags: java, generics, interface

Suppose I have the following interface:

```
public interface Interface<T extends Number>{
    public Vector<Interface<T>> getVector();
}
```

and the following class implementing that interface:

```
public abstract class C<T extends Number> implements Interface<T>{

    private Vector<C<T>> vector;
    public Vector<Interface<T>> getVector(){ //errror
         return this.vector;
    }
}
```

Why is not legal returning a `Vector<C<T>>` meanwhile is legal ( obviously) returning a `Vector<Interface<T>>`. `C` is actually implementing `Interface`, so it should be possible, right? What am I missing?

EDIT:

why this work for non generics interface? Is this actually a generic related problem?

```
public interface Interface{
        public Interface getVector();
    }

public abstract class C implements Interface {

    private C;
    public Interface getVector(){ //errror
         return this.c;
    }
}
```

Comment: The technical term for what you are describing is **covariance**. Search for that, and you'll find lots of duplicates, including this one: [Any simple way to explain why I cannot do `List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Dog>()`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346763/any-simple-way-to-explain-why-i-cannot-do-listanimal-animals-new-arraylistdo)

Comment: @Daniel Pryden: thank you for the technical term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `Vector` is explicitly made up of `Interface<T>`, not things that extend `Interface<T>`, I believe this would work if you changed the definition to

```
 public Vector<? extends Interface<T>> getVector();
```

The problem is that for some `V implements T` or `V extends T` that `Foo<V>` is not a supertype of `Foo<T>`. The compiler does not test inheritance on the generic arguments unless you explicitly indicate that extension point.

Using `Vector<? extends Interface<T>>` means "allow any class that implements or extends `Interface<T>`, whereas `Vector<Interface<T>>` means a vector consisting only of `Interface<T>` items.

Perhaps it's more concrete to consider that `List<Integer>` is not an acceptable replacement for `List<Number>` despite `Integer` extending `Number` for precisely the same reason.

**update**:

I tested this and the following compiles without any errors or warnings

```
interface Interface<T extends Number>{
    public Vector<? extends Interface<T>> getVector();
}

abstract class C<T extends Number> implements Interface<T>{

    private Vector<C<T>> vector;
    public Vector<? extends Interface<T>> getVector(){
         return this.vector;
    }
}
```

Comment: You also have to change the method signature to `public Vector<C<T>> getVector()` in subclass `C` for this to compile. `Vector<C<T>>` is not a subclass of `Vector<Interface<T>>`, so returning something that is not a subclass of what the method is supposed to return is obviously not allowed.

Comment: +1: but I edited my question. Could you help me to clarify that? is a problem related to generics right?

Comment: @toto2: no, it compiles just fine with the modification I suggest (see my edit)

Comment: OK.  I had left `Vector<Interface<T>>` in the method declaration for `C`.  Nonetheless, I think it's clearer to use `Vector<C<T>>` as the return type in the declaration.

Answer (score 1):

It's the way generics work.  They are not "covariant": if you have class `AClass` and its subclass `SubAClass`, `Vector<SubAClass>` is not a subclass of `Vector<A>`.  (Note however that `SubAClass[]` is a subclass of `AClass[]`.)

EDIT:

The seemingly obvious:

```
public ArrayList<Object> blah() {
    return new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

won't compile because `ArrayList<String>` is not a subclass `ArrayList<Object>`. So in your case you can't return a `Vector<C<T>>` instance for a `Vector<Interface<T>>`.

Comment: +1: so my guess is correct right? Is a problem related to generics?

Comment: @toto2: Reification has nothing to do with it. Your examples are correct, but the reason it works the way it does is not because of erasure, but because Java's generics are *invariant* (and the `T extends Foo` or `T super Foo` syntaxes are just a workaround for this) but the feature desired here is *covariance*. True, arrays are reified, and arrays are covariant, but the two are completely independent qualities.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel.  I took out my Effective Java by Bloch where covariant and reified are defined at the start of Item 25. I indeed inverted their meaning.  I edited my answer.  For reference, arrays being reified means that when you add a String to an array `myArray[0] = "blah"` there is a runtime check that `myArray` is indeed a `String[]` (or a supertype of `String[]`).  An `ArrayStoreException` is thrown if it's not the case.  In some way, reification is the opposite model from type erasure used by generics.